# Java - GUI elements not visible in external class

Tags: java, javafx

I have this main class in which I make my gui and another class in which I want to define further. The problem is arrives upon calling elements from the main class. The gui elements are according to the problem log not visible fields.
I have tried setting these fields public and added getters and setters but without result.

Main:

```
JButton btnExecute = new JButton("Execute");
    btnExecute.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Commandline.buttonExecuteClicked();}});
```

External class:

```
public class Commandline extends mainGUI {

public static void buttonExecuteClicked() {
    //Inputveld
    String inputCommand = cmdInputField.getText();
    String eerdereInputCommands = cmdInput.getText();
    cmdInput.setText(eerdereInputCommands + inputCommand + "\n");
```

Comment: Is this even `JavaFX`? At the very least, you should know the technology you are using. MouseAdapter seems to suggest this is `awt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the gui elements to static... solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the text object/whatever object into the method:

```
 Commandline.buttonExecuteClicked(cmdInput);
```